# Compile VLC for IOS Simulator（Xcode 4.6， IOS SDK 6.1 ， Mac OSX10.8）

Tags: ios, vlc, xcode4.6

HI~ I try to compile VLC for IOS, and below is my steps:

1. git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/ios.git
2. cd ios
3. ./buildMobileVLC.sh -s

After that, I got the error bellow:

> Making install in lib
>
> make  install-am
>
> CC       fribidi.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-arabic.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-bidi.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-bidi-types.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-deprecated.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-joining.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-joining-types.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-mem.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-mirroring.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-run.lo
>
> CC       fribidi-shape.lo
>
> cd ../lib && make  libfribidi-char-sets.la
>
> make[5]: *** No rule to make target `libfribidi-char-sets.la'.  Stop.
>
> make[4]: *** [../charset/libfribidi-char-sets.la] Error 2
>
> make[3]: *** [install] Error 2
>
> make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
>
> make: *** [.fribidi] Error 2

I have try to solve the error by using goole, stack overflow and VideoLAN.
But I didn't see the same error like me.

Please help me!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the version of autoconf and automake that the build script creates.

I had to

```
brew unlink autoconf && brew unlink automake
```

to get it to build.